# Change value aggregation, if condition node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, if-statement, aggregate

How to change **aggragte** value in node js - mongodb

i have `$project` :

```
        $project : {
            type: '$data.type',
        }
```

and it give me output :

```
'type' : [
'bold',
'bold',
'regular',
'bold',
'regular'
]
```

the i want to change the output

**if bold, then thick, else thin**

i have try to use `$cond` and `$switch`, but idk why the i get just 1 output and that's default output

```
type: {
                        $switch : {
                            branches : [ 
                                {
                                case : { $eq : ['$data.type', 'bold']}, then: 'thick'
                                },
                                {
                                case : { $eq : ['$data.type', 'regular']}, then: 'thin'
                                },
                            ],
                            
                            default: ""
                        }
                    },
```

output :

```
"type": "",
```

can u all help me to solve  this ?
i have trying the `$cond` `$eq` too, but the output still default output

**thank you for helping guys**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$map` helps to modify or go through all the data. `$cond` helps to add condition to the data

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      type: {
        $map: {
          input: "$type",
          in: {
            $cond: [{$eq: ["$$this","bold"]},
              "thick",
              "thin"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iMWA1mOmaK2)**